# How to remove xml tags with numeric values from string?

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to process XML data . But sometimes, xml tags are in numeric form, i.e.<1>, <2>, etc. I want to replace these numeric tags  with some specific string so that after processing I can revert back the values of xml tags.

I am looking for regex which can match all strings for following format,

```
 <some numerical number> and </some numerical number>
```

Comment: Please use some [xml parser](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=XML+parser+in+java+&oq=XML+parser+in+java+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2595j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) rather than regex.

Comment: @SURESH ATTA: I think tags like `<1>` are not well-formed XML, see [XML Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#dt-stag). XML parsers may refuse to accept such input. Which one do you recommend for such non-well-formed XML?

Comment: @Halfbit ..you are absolutely right ...xml parsers do  not allow numeric tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
System.out.println("<12>".matches("^</*[0-9]+>$"));
```

Then you can wait for closing bracket, calculate the position, and substring.

Comment: Is it possible to replace <numeric> by <sometext_numeric> ?

Comment: Try to `System.out.println("</fsdf_12>".matches("^</*[A-Za-z]+_[0-9]+>$"));` You can find more info [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html). Hope this helps :)